# How can open a browser popup window with a message, right from the Selenium API code?

Tags: java, selenium, browser

Instead of debugging a very slowly running Selenium test cases, I want to be able to open a browser based pop-up window from with in the Selenium Java code. How can I do that ?

Comment: show us what you have done so far ?

Comment: What is your use-case?

Comment: I have had not much idea, because I did not get any clue which is about what is provided by the Selenium API towards this purpose.
My use case is this:-- I am working on a Selenium framework developed by a mega e-commerce website. Each test case is an xml file, containing tags with keywords, which are pointers to a class and a method in it to implement some functionality. I am able to debug any method.But it is tedious. Instead, I want to create a public method which can generate a browser alert with some contextual data message, so that this can be called by any method in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but possibly this can help you:

```
public void callAlert(String alertMessage){
   driver.executeScript("alert(\"" + alertMessage + "\");");
```

}

Comment: Let me try this at my earliest and will get back.